# Launch threads continuously with predefined interval between threads

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I'm currently using a third-party API to fetch results, using a REST client (Retrofit).

The problem is that the amount of requests per second that I can do to the API is limited with interval: I can't do more than **10 requests per second with 100 ms between requests**.

As I want to multi-thread those calls for performance purpose, I wonder how could I manage this interval of 100 ms between each API call?

I can't sleep 100 ms in a single thread since it's bounded to the current thread.

Is there any way to use a *shared sleep* between multiple threads?
Or do you have any idea how to implement this?

Thanks.

Comment: You want the execution to overlap, right? So [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) won't work for you. If that is the case... why? Surely you can make the request asynchronously fast enough so that overlapping is not a problem. Then even [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) would work.

Comment: You only need threading in handling the responses, if at all. Making the requests can be centralised.

Comment: @Theraot : Some threads in my app will call 3-rd party API through a singleton REST client. I want that no matter which thread calls this client, an overlap of 100ms between calls. I do not think that timer will do the Job or I misunderstood something.

Comment: @Caleth : multiple threads call call the REST client.

Comment: @Rouliboy overlap means that it will awake a thread to make a request even if there are other threads that haven't ended. That is, if you have an interval of 100ms without overlap, they will queue up when it takes too long to make the request. On the other hand, an interval of 100ms with overlap can have multiple threads requesting at the same time when they take longer than 100ms to make the request. If you do not want overlap (i.e. you want them to queue up), then Timer will work. Now, are requests slow enough that overlap matters? Using Timer, there would be no queue, if requests are fast.

Comment: Also, please note I am saying request. I am not talking about waiting for a response.  If you can make the requests asynchronously (that means, you can request and get the response later, without having the thread blocked waiting), then you are likely to be able to make the requests fast.

Comment: @Theraot thanks for explanations. Actually we do not care about response time. If Response takes 5s for each call, we can still make call every 100 ms.But even with your explanantions I do not see how to have this "shared" interval of 100ms between each call?

Comment: @Rouliboy alright, so, this is the difference between using Timer and using ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor: The timer executes ecverything in a single background thread. On the other hand ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor uses a thread pool, thus one or more threads. Now, ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor gives you two options: scheduleAtFixedRate which will execute at a given interval regardless of how long the execution takes, and scheduleWithFixedDelay which will execute with a given delay between executions. See [scheduleAtFixedRate vs scheduleWithFixedDelay](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24649842/402022).

Comment: Ok thanks, I understand way better, explanations are clear. But I do not think it matches with what I'm doing. Let me explain: on my REST client I have several endpoints (let say `getToken` and `getData`). Now I can have multiple users which request at the same time on of those endpoints. What I want is a way to add an intevral between each call. With your solution, it's more about fetching data every 100ms, but on my side I want to block the call for 100ms. But the users could not make any call for 1hour for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have multiple endpoints and multiple users making requests concurrently.

Then you want to make sure that these requests happen at most at some rate, globally.

---

This is the basic idea:

You can add the requests you want to do to a queue. More precisely a `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` of `Runnable` (you will create custom runnables for each endpoint). Multiple threads can interact with this single queue concurrently.

Then you can use a `Timer` to execute a command that takes one item from the queue and executes it. This way each interval a request is made, regardless of the rate at which they are added to the queue (unless it is empty, of course).

*Replace `Timer` with `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` if needed.*

---

You can improve upon this by stopping the `Timer` (or stopping the `ScheduledFuture`) if you are in a period of inactivity※. Plus, starting/scheduling it again when adding items to the queue (if it was stopped).

※: Keep track of the time of the last request. If you took something from the queue, update the time to the current time. If you did not, compare the time to the current time... if too much (for some definition of too much) time has passed, then you are in a period of inactivity.

---

I'm not sure how do you handle responses. However, independently of whatever or not they are synchronous. You have the option to pass a custom `Consumer` where you can pass the result. In fact, your custom `Runnable` (the one you add to the queue) could hold the `Consumer` from the client.

Comment: Seems really nice, thanks for the clear explanations and I love that solution!